# Given ¬(p ∨ q), prove (¬p ∧ ¬q) using propositional logic operators.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I believe there is a way to prove it as both terms have equal truth tables.
But how using propositional logic operators ?

Comment: The first one says "If either is true result is false" the second says "result is true when both are false". So the say the same thing.

Comment: No idea ? No attempt done ?

Comment: See [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Informal_proof).

Comment: It is intuitive like recurrency to me was years ago.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prove that $\neg p$ and $\neg q$.

Assume $p$. Then $p \lor q$. That contradicts $\neg(p \lor q)$. Therefore $\neg p$.

Do the same to prove $\neg q$ and you're done.

Comment: That was kind of advice I was looking for, proof solved.